# $T(n)=4 \cdot T \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3} \right) + \log^2 n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computational-complexity

What is time complexity of

$$T(n)=4 \cdot T \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3} \right) + \log^2 n$$

I cannot solve it by recursion tree or any other method.

we have the base T(1) = 1

I may think about sandwich theorem but dont know how to use.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: is time complexity the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b$ be the base of the logarithm, and let $n = b^m$. Then

$$ T(b^m) = 4 \cdot T\left( b^{m/2 - \log 3} \right) + \log^2 n $$

which suggests setting

$$ S(m) = T(b^m) \qquad \qquad T(n) = S(\log n)$$

and then first solving the recurrence

$$ S(m) = 4 \cdot S\left(\frac{m}{2} - \log 3 \right) + m^2 $$

where I've assumed by $\log^2 n$ you mean $(\log n)^2$ rather than $\log \log n$.

Comment: Do we eventually get $T(n)=(\log n)^2\cdot\log\log n$ using Mater theorem? I just ignored the constant $\log 3$.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe: $T(n) = \Theta( (\log n)^2 \cdot \log \log n )$ looks like what I would expect, although I haven't bothered to consult the theorem to make sure.

Comment: how deep will the tree of s(m) go? suppose solving by recursion tree

Answer (score 0):

The following is an upper bound, which probably is good enough for any analysis.

We have 
$$T(n)\leq4 \cdot T \left(\frac{n}{3} \right) + n$$ 
Using [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) we get $O(n^{\log_34})$.